# How can I null-check this?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: GetLiter(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
    "Estimated bill \n\n\n" + snapshot.data * 0.00556 + " $",
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  ), // Text
), // FutureBuilder
```

I have "*An expression whose value can be 'null' must be null-checked before it can be dereferenced.*" error in snapshot.data. How can I null-check this?

GetLiter() func is here =>

```
Future<Object?> GetLiter() async {
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Liter");

  DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();

  // print(event.snapshot.value);
  return event.snapshot.value;
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `GetLiter`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I edited it

Comment: I think you need to check if the snapshot isn’t null and after that

Comment: @NMZ yeah but I don't know how to do that. Where can I put the if()?

Comment: @mberker0 before you added this to the Text ,after you opening the arrow func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FutureBuilders do not wait for the future to complete before they build and therefore `snapshot.data` could be null. You need to check this before you build or else the build will fail. Try this out:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


FutureBuilder(
  future: GetLiter(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasError){
      print(snapshot.error);
    }
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return Text(
        "Estimated bill \n\n\n" + snapshot.data! * 0.00556 + " $",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  }
),
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped a lot but now I have another error ;( When I try to multiply this snapshot.data! * 0.00556 it gives "The operator '*' isn't defined for the type 'Object'." error. Can you help with this too?

Comment: or I have to ask another question for this error?

Comment: I think youre problem here is that you have your GetLiter method returning `Future<Object?>` which means that the compiler doesnt know that its supposed to be a number. Im going to assume it returns a double given the context clues so I would change `Future<Object?> GetLiter() async {` to `Future<double> GetLiter() async {`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snapshot.hasData` on your `builder` to check if it is null. For example:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: GetLiter(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Nothing here');
    return Text(
      "Estimated bill \n\n\n" + snapshot.data * 0.00556 + " $",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    )
  }, // Text
),
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the same error ;(

Comment: After checking `snapshot.hasData` (or checking `if (snapshot.data != null)`, you will need to use `snapshot.data!` since [only local variables can be type-promoted](https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons#property-or-this).

Answer (score 0):

While using `FutureBuilder` you need to await for data and handle loading state and null data.

```dart
child: FutureBuilder<Object?>(
  future: GetLiter(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else if (snapshot.hasData &&
        snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      return Text("Got Data");
    } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text("no Data");
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
    } else {
      return Text("others");
    }
  },
),
```

More about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: OP also will need to use `snapshot.data!` after checking `snapshot.hasData`.